# get the file size on file browsing

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an asp fileupload control, i want to know,,is it possible to get the filesize the moment i browse a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible through Active X in Explorer only but for that also it requires Active X on from the browser setting, so it can only be used if you are sure that each and every user will use IE and that settings will be on.

In other case you can always check the size on server, but drawback of that method is that you have already uploaded the file.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily.  Most of your code (JavaScript aside) is running on the server and that means performing a submit after the file is already uploaded.